# Scrape the last item from a list of varying length

Tags: r, rvest

I am scraping economic data from a yearly ranking - always scraping the first value and the last value. Now the problem is that the lists vary in length every year so that the last node ist always different.

```
Year Last list item
1997 89
1998 94
1999 112
2000 76
```

and so on

Is there a possibility to automatically get to the last node?

```
page_call <- read_html("https://...")
input <- page_call %>%
  html_nodes(xpath="/html/body/div/div[Number of last node]") %>%
  html_text()
```

Thank you!

Comment: can you share the url so I can see if I can add an css answer as well?

Answer (score 1):

[`last()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/last) should work:

```
page_call <- read_html("https://...")
input <- page_call %>%
  html_nodes(xpath="/html/body/div/div[last()]") %>%
  html_text()
```

Comment: It does! Thanks so much!